# JSLint Expected '%' and instead saw '%'

Tags: javascript, jslint

I have code that starts off with

```
<% 
  function selected()
  {
```

at the start of my code and JSLint gives the error

Problem at line 1 character 1: Expected '%' and instead saw '%'.

This code works just fine and has for a long time. I was just trying to run this against JSLint hoping to improve my code. JSLint stops at this error and will not scan the rest of the code.

Problem at line 1 character 1: Stopping. (0% scanned).

I was just hoping someone had an idea why this was wrong. It is production code and won't be changed but it is always a good idea to learn why something should not be written this way.

Thanks.

Comment: can you not delete that?

Comment: ASP Jscript? That's not gonna go so well :)

Comment: It'll go fine, you just have to warn JSLint about the extra global variables. So JSHint might be better in this case.

Comment: It seems there is ASP Jscript at the top and Javascript used in the HTML, nice catch by everyone. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a Classic ASP script using [JScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript) rather than traditional Javascript?

If so, I'm not sure JSLint is going to work properly unless you strip out the Classic ASP-specific stuff (`<% %>`)

Answer (score 1):

JSLint will work fine, but you have to paste in the part that is just JavaScript.

The `<% %>` stuff tells the server that the text inside it is a server-side script to run while outputting the page. So just select the stuff inside, the actual JavaScript, and run that against JSLint.

Answer (score 0):

JSLint works with Javascript, and `<%` is not part of Javascript. Just remove this token when you run your code through JSLint and you should get more meaningful results.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to jun jslint on non-js code is it in a jsp file or something.